# Node closes DB connection either before inserts or does not close at all

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the following code that does the following:

- Opens DB connection (using [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)).
- Call Twitter Trends API (once or more for different places).
- Go through the trends items and store each one into DB.
- Close DB connection.

I tried a straight forward code. I faced the following error first.

`Error: Connection terminated by user`

Here is the code.

```
client.connect();

const text = 'INSERT INTO TRENDS(AS_OF, location_name, name, tweet_volume, rank) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *';

T.get('trends/place', { id: 2295424 }, function(err, data, response) {
    data_json = data[0];
    var rankNum = 0;
    console.log(data_json.locations[0].name);
    for (var item of data_json.trends) {
        rankNum++;
        var values = [data_json.as_of, data_json.locations[0].name, item.name, item.tweet_volume, rankNum];
        client.query(text, values)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.rows[0])
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
    };
    client.end();
});
```

It appeared, the DB connection (`client.end()`) was called and closed before the `client.query()` could run. So, I rewrote my code to wait for the client.query to complete and then call client.end using async/await.

```
client.connect();

const text = 'INSERT INTO TRENDS(AS_OF, location_name, name, tweet_volume, rank) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *';

T.get('trends/place', { id: 23424848 }, function (err, data, response) {
    data_json = data[0];
    var rankNum = 0;
    console.log(data_json.locations[0].name);

    function insRows(){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        for (var item of data_json.trends) {
        rankNum++;
        var values = [data_json.as_of, data_json.locations[0].name, item.name, item.tweet_volume, rankNum];
        client.query(text, values)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.rows[0])
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
        };
    });
    };

    async function closeDBConnection(){
        const a = await insRows();
        client.end();
        return 0;
    };

    closeDBConnection().then( v => {
         console.log(v);
    });
});
```

This code with async/await does run fine, however the DB connection is not closed and node just hangs for me to CTRL+C.

- Node version: v9.2.1
- I run the program using command: `node app.js`

### Update 1

Updated code with Promise array and async/await. This does not work:

```
client.connect();

const text = 'INSERT INTO TRENDS(AS_OF, location_name, name, tweet_volume, rank) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *';
T.get('trends/place', { id: 23424848 }, function(err, data, response) {
    const data_json = data[0];
    let rankNum = 0;
    const queryPromises = [];
    console.log(data_json.locations[0].name);
    async function insRows() {
        for (let item of data_json.trends) {
            rankNum++;
            const values = [data_json.as_of, data_json.locations[0].name, item.name, item.tweet_volume, rankNum];
            queryPromises.push(client.query(text, values)
                .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
                .catch(e => console.error(e.stack)));
        };
    };

    (async = () => {
        await Promise.all(queryPromises);
        client.end();
    });
});
```

I also tried:

```
    async function insRows(){
     /* same as above*/
    }
    await Promise.all(queryPromises);
    client.end();
```

I get the following error (`node app_ans.js`):

```
        await Promise.all(queryPromises);
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never calls `resolve` of the promise you create, but you don't need to create your own promise since `client.query` already returns a promise. I would write it like this:

```
const data_json = data[0];
let rankNum = 0;
const queryPromises = [];

for (let item of data_json.trends) {
    rankNum++;
    const values = [data_json.as_of, data_json.locations[0].name, item.name, item.tweet_volume, rankNum];
    queryPromises.push(client.query(text, values)
        .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
        .catch(e => console.error(e.stack)));
};
await Promise.all(queryPromises);
client.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am going to try this out in a bit.

Comment: Strange I got hit with this error. I am on Node v9.2.1

`/apps/twttrend/app_ans.js:37
    await Promise.all(queryPromises);
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
`

Comment: @Guru you need to make `insRows` an async function

Comment: Something is still wrong. I get the same error. I have updated the question with the entire code.

Comment: You can remove the `async =` part. You need to make the callback to `T.get` async. `T.get('trends/place', { id: 2295424 }, async function(...` `insRows` does not need to be its own function.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, I assume you are using **npm-request** package to place GET request to twitter [trends/places api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place), if yes, I suggest using **request-promise**; which allows us to use Async/Await directly as it supports Promises instead of callback. That being said, the issue could be with the way you are framing the GET request. use `T.get('trends/place?id=23424848'` instead of `T.get('trends/place', { id: 23424848 }`

You may also consider the below code:

```
const T = require('request-promise')
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()

await client.connect()

const getTrendsAndUpdate = async (id) => {
    const text = 'INSERT INTO TRENDS(AS_OF, location_name, name, tweet_volume, rank) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *';

    const closeDBConnection = async () => {
        await client.end();
        console.log('DB Connection closed')
        return 0;
    }

    try{
        const data_json = await T.get('trends/place?id='+id, {json:true});
        let trends = data_json['trends'];
        let as_of = data_json['as_of'];
        let location_name = data_json['locations']['name'];
        let rankNum = 0;
        let a = await trends.forEach(async item => {
            rankNum++;
            let values = [data_json.as_of, data_json.locations[0].name, item.name, item.tweet_volume, rankNum];
            let res = await client.query(text, values)
            console.log(res.rows[0])
        });
        if(a){
            await closeDBConnection()
            return
        }
    } catch(e){ console.error(e.stack) }
}

getTrendsAndUpdate(23424848)
```

Hope this resolves the issue and points you in right direction.

Comment: Thanks, Nagaraja. I was using "twit" npm package to connect to Twitter API. I was referring to node-postgres.com for examples, but was falling short. I have it working now.